# Sort list of dictionaries according to index

Tags: python, dictionary

I am trying to sort a list with dictionaries.

I have the following example:

```
test = [{'index':'22','text':'a'},{'index':'21','text':'b'},{'index':'28','text':'c'}]
```

I tried sorting this list in increasing order of the key "index" with the following code:

```
sorted(test,key = lambda k:k['index'])
```

But I get the error "builtin_function_or_method object is not iterable".

Can someone help me?

Comment: What version of Python are you using? Your code works for me on Python3.6

Comment: What IDE are you using? Also, this won't sort in numerical order because `index` values are strings

Comment: works on python2.7 as well

Comment: may be you rename variables or do import?

Comment: is this all your code? are you redefining `test` anywhere?

Comment: add a space after the `:`

Comment: @mad.meesh works with and without space, tried it

Comment: well aren’t i a dumb dumb

Comment: @roganjosh it still sorts, even if values not converted , tested with `reverse`

Comment: Since people are throwing ideas all over the shop here, I'm taking a stab at you using Spyder as an IDE which can cause this kind of unusual behaviour. So rather than **everyone guessing** can we wait for feedback from OP?

Comment: @vash_the_stampede - sorting on string value rather than int value works in the sense that it won't throw errors, but it'll do things that are probably unintended like putting "100" before "99".

Comment: @PeterDeGlopper dually noted just saying that specifically is not throwing this particular error

Comment: That is definitely true.

Answer (score 0):

Try This:

```
newlist = sorted(test, key=lambda k: int(k['index']))
```

Comment: Why? There is nothing wrong with their code that would throw such an error.

Comment: Ya you are right. Sorry for not reading properly. COde works on both python2 & 3.

Comment: Note that OP *might* want `key=lambda k: int(k['index'])`.